# How do I align div vertically like in picture

Tags: html, css

I have a html code like this

```
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters"></span>
<a>links 1</a>
<a>links 2</a>
<a>links 3</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters"></span>
<a>links 1</a>
<a>links 2</a>
<a>links 3</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters"></span>
<a>links 1</a>
<a>links 2</a>
<a>links 3</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters"></span>
<a>links 1</a>
<a>links 2</a>
<a>links 3</a>
</div>
```

Having written my code, with additional css I get this ouput

[image: code result]

But this is what is suppose to be the expected output
[image: expected result]

Anyone know how to accomplish this using only css and without adding addition div wrapper.
The purpose is so that it would easily adjust to the screen of any devices.  Love to know if there is some other way to do it.

(If this is a duplicate post kindly inform me immediately and give me the link of the other similar post I could not find anything like this since I could not ascertain the exact keywords to use. Thanks)

Comment: you want Masonry grids try searching on Google you will get help there

Comment: I'd love to hear the reasons of those who voted you down, this is a very interesting question

Comment: Probably because it's a question asking how to do something, and doesn't show any actual attempts from the original poster of how they tried to do it.. I'm guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
.box {
    width:60%;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
.group {
    width:60%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:auto;
    background:#ededed;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
}
.group a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:10px auto;
}
.big-letters {
    font-size:30px;
    color:#f60;
    display:block;
}
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86m1299e/)

this way you can keep that *"snake"* (up --> down and up again) order instead of the usual html float *left to right*

Comment: This helped me, I also followed an example in here http://w3bits.com/demo/responsive-css-masonry/

And I guess there is no way to avoid using media queries.

Answer (score 1):

try using column count like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
width: 100%;
max-width: 800px;
-moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;}
.group {    
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;    
}
.group a{
    display: list-item;
}
.big-letters{
    font-size: 44px;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters">A</span>
<a href="#">links 1</a>
<a href="#">links 2</a>
<a href="#">links 3</a>
<a href="#">links 1</a>
<a href="#">links 2</a>
<a href="#">links 3</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters">B</span>
<a href="#">links 1</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters">C</span>
<a href="#">links 1</a>
<a href="#">links 2</a>
<a href="#">links 3</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters">D</span>
<a href="#">links 1</a>
<a href="#">links 2</a>
<a href="#">links 3</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters">E</span>
<a href="#">links 1</a>
<a href="#">links 2</a>
<a href="#">links 3</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters">F</span>
<a href="#">links 1</a>
<a href="#">links 2</a>
<a href="#">links 3</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters">G</span>
<a href="#">links 1</a>
<a href="#">links 2</a>
<a href="#">links 3</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters">H</span>
<a href="#">links 1</a>
<a href="#">links 2</a>
<a href="#">links 3</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="big-letters">I</span>
<a href="#">links 1</a>
<a href="#">links 2</a>
<a href="#">links 3</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: here some reference: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-masonry-grid-layouts-to-your-wordpress-site-with-just-css/